# Fermat's last theorem for $n=7$

Tags: number-theory

Which is the most elementary way of showing that $$x^7+y^7=z^7$$ has no positive integer solutions?

Comment: $7$ because it's the first prime not covered by [elementary proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents)?

Comment: According to this comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140459/has-fermats-last-theorem-per-se-been-used#comment362803_140470 from Franz Lemmermeyer, FLT for exponent 7 can be proved "using a standard 2-descent."

Comment: I recommend to consult Ribenboim's book "13 Lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem" (Springer, 1979).

Answer (score 1):

The most elementary way of proving FLT for exponent $7$ is using a $2$-descent; the first steps closely follow the original arguments by Lamé, Genocchi and Lebesgue, the actual $2$-descent simplifies their calculations that followed. This is beautifully explained in Elkies' article on the Klein quartic available [here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/elkies.pdf). I did something similar [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9903207.pdf) before I learned about Elkies' article.

Comment: Pages 75-76 in Elkies' article reduces the problem to $-7y^2=4x^3+21x^2+28x$ and then states "In fact we can apply a 2-descent directly to (3.12) using the 2-torsion point (0; 0), and then find that this point is the only rational point of (3.12) other than the point at infinity" without providing the details. Similarly, your proof reduces the problem to $y^2=x(x^2-3\cdot 7^2 x+2^4\cdot 7^3)$ and then states "a simple 2-descent shows that E has rank $0$" again without providing the details. Can you please add the details of the 2-descent to complete the proof?